# Как привязать к Chart несколько источников данных?

Tags: c#, диаграммы

Есть объект Chart. В качестве DataSource я указал List где Bar это структура (High, Low, Open, Close). Все работает. Необходимо добавить еще один источник данных для другой серии этого же чарта. Данные типа List, где DateVal структура (DateTime, Value). Можно добавлять данные непосредственно через

```
Chart.Series[1].Points.Add()
```

Но хотелось бы все-таки через привязку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать Points.DataBind.

Например, так:

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBind(ds1, "id", "Data", null);
chart1.Series[1].Points.DataBind(ds2, "id", "Data", null);
```

Где ds1 и ds2 некие источники данных.

Тогда у Вас каждая серия будет получать данные из своего собственного источника.